# Giving variables from html to python

Tags: javascript

I want to give variables from html to python using javascript.

On clicking navbar coded as:

```
aa.html      
   <a href="{{url_for('to_python')}}" id='aa'>hello</a>
```

Where `to_python` route goes to `bb.html`

I want to pass variable `animal='dog'` when clicking on aa.html href.

---

I tried using

```
$("#aa").attr("href", '?animal=dog')
```

But this does not go to bb.html.
The result is `aa.html?animal=dog` ( I want `bb.html?animal=dog`)

---

※Also I would like to know a way to pass variables on method `POST` using javascript. Any Ideas?

---

I tried using

```
$('#aa').on("click", function(){
  $.post('/to_python', {animal:'dog'}, function(res){
  .....something
  }
```

But this code sometime work, but sometimes not. Do not know what is wrong.

Comment: use forms or ajax....!

Comment: @Jai This is used on navbar... so `form` is not what i am looking for. and `ajax` i used `$.post` but it sometimes does not work..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the URL using JavaScript, try something like

```
var $aa = $("#aa");
$aa.attr("href", $aa.attr("href").split("?")[0] + "?animal=dog");
```

That is, instead of replacing the href, grab everything before any parameters it might already have, then replace the parameters with what you want. For example,

- `<a href="hello">` would become `<a href="hello?animal=dog">`
- `<a href="hello?parameter=yes">` would become `<a href="hello?animal=dog">`

etc. If you need to retain other parameters, you'll need to do a little bit more:

```
var $aa = $("#aa");
var currentHref = $aa.attr("href");
$aa.attr("href", currentHref + (currentHref.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&") + "animal=dog");
```

This way

- `<a href="hello">` would become `<a href="hello?animal=dog">`
- `<a href="hello?parameter=yes">` would become `<a href="hello?parameter=yes&animal=dog">`